# Getting "Tuple element name is inferred. Please use language version 7.1 or greater to access an element by its inferred name."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

We have the following code that has been working fine in our UWP app until today after we updated Visual Studio 2017 to the latest **15.3**.

```
private void Test()
{
    var groups = new List<(Guid key, IList<(string, bool)> items)>();

    var items = new List<(string, bool)>
    {
        ("a", true),
        ("b", false),
        ("c", false)
    };
    var group = (Guid.NewGuid(), items);

    groups.Add(group);
}
```

There is no error message but this in the output window

> Tuple element name 'items' is inferred. Please use language version
>   7.1 or greater to access an element by its inferred name.

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Comment: @itsme86 well, I can't just upgrade it to use C#7.1 since it's a UWP app.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question as such, but types like `new List<(Guid key, IList<(string, bool)> items)>` make decent use cases *against* tuples. No operation on that except for adding items is efficient or obvious -- consider if you don't want something like `Dictionary<Guid, HashSet<string>>` instead. (Obviously the proper types depend entirely on your use case, but nested lists of tuples tend not to be it.)

Comment: @itsme86 Do you know how to specify language version 7.1? I'm assuming this is actually just a preview-related error message, and not yet available in non-preview Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @Jessica moving to C# 7.1 should be just fine for a UWP application. The C# 7.1 compiler is already being used, the language version flag only controls what features are available.

Comment: @JaredPar can you please show me how?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Project->Properties->Build->Advanced->Language Version->C# latest Minor Version

Comment: Thank you! This actually works without the workaround. I didn't know I could do this.

Comment: in rare case you have no Visual Studio, just add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to your csproj file

Comment: Thanks python_kaa, put it under <PropertyGroup> and works on MacOS

Comment: I had the same problem using VsCode, and add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` did **not** worked for me. I needed to be explicit, so... Adding `<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>` inside `<PropertyGroup>` solved for me.

Answer (score 11):

<strike>Looks like this is a [breaking change](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/infer-tuple-names.md#drawbacks) in C# *7.1*.</strike> (as pointed out by @JulienCouvreur, this is actually a bug, but the workaround below should still work though).

---

**Workaround**

Try giving a *name* (e.g. use the same name `items` from `IList<(string, bool)> items` to be consistent) explicitly to `items` (i.e. the list instance).

```
var group = (Guid.NewGuid(), items: items);
```

Comment: No, this is a bug. The breaking change described in the spec involves an extension method, which becomes hidden by newly named field.

Comment: Hey @JulienCouvreur thanks for letting me know! I thought they are related but clearly you know this better than me. :)

Answer (score 11):

This a confirmed bug, introduced in 15.3. The fix will ship as part of a servicing release (15.3.2).

The issue is tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21518

Comment: Do we still need to select "C# latest Minor Version" for this to work with a target Framework of .Net Framework 4.7? I have VS 2017 15.3.3 but I get the compile error unless I switch to latest minor version under the Advanced Build settings.

Comment: @Steve Young, The compiler doesn't know anything about target framework. The C# language rules (and in this case the bug) are determined by the "language version", but not target framework.
This bug was fixed in 15.3.2, so if you can still repro on 15.3.3, please re-open the linked issue or open a new one. Thanks